# What is the difference between loading rest of the page when the user reaches bottom with only javascript in comperison two javascript and ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Maybe the question sounds a little bit confusing.
So i wanted to reduce page loading time,by loading a part of the page with html and css and then i add script at the bottom of the body  with event listener and function which detects when has user scrolled to the bottom of the page.If user reaches the bottom of the page i load javascript nodes texts and images.
What is the difference between loading images as creating image nodes and adding it source or retriving images and text with ajax inside javascript.

Answer (score 0):

None. Ajax is the name for what you're talking about.

> With Ajax, web applications can send and retrieve data from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)